# Wie kann man wissen, ob zwei Wörter Homonyme sind?

Tags: terminology

Der Begriff von Homonymen ist weit verbreitet.

> Wort, das mit einem andern gleich lautet, den gleichen Wortkörper hat (aber in der Bedeutung [und Herkunft] verschieden ist) ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Homonym))
>
> Als Homonym bezeichnet man ein Wort, das für verschiedene Begriffe oder unterschiedliche Einzeldinge steht. ([Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym))

Ich finde es schwierig zu bestimmen, ob zwei Wörter Homonyme sind. Zum Beispiel ist es deutlich, dass "der Ball" zwei verschiedene Bedeutungen hat: "Kugel" und "Tanzvergnügen". Es ist aber nicht so klar, ob "der Freund" eine oder zwei Bedeutungen hat ("Bekannter" und "Liebhaber").

Gibt es eine offizielle Stelle, die entscheidet, ab wann etwas als eine eigenständige Bedeutung zählt?

Comment: Eine Anregung, um den Titel zu verbessern, "Wie kann man entscheiden, ob zwei Wörter Homonyme sind?" Ich hab allerdings keine Ahnung, ob es hier auf GL&U sinnvoll ist, Titel nachträglich zu verändern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nein, es gibt keine offizielle Stelle, die so etwas entscheidet. Wie in anderen Sprachen auch, listen Wörterbücher verschiedene Bedeutungen auf, aber die Klassifikation ist die Entscheidung der jeweiligen Redaktion.

Üblicherweise bezeichnet man aber als Homonym nicht ein Wort wie Freund, das einen gewissen Bedeutungsspielraum hat, sondern Worte, die tatsächlich verschiedenen Ursprung haben oder zumindest deutlich verschiedene Bedeutungen haben.

Die genaue Unterscheidung ist aber wie immer fließend.

Ich verweise auch auf das beliebte Spiel [Teekesselchen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teekesselchen).

wo gleich am Anfang der Unterschied zwischen Homonym und Polysem gemacht wird.

Comment: Das Spiel Teekesselchen kannte ich gar nicht; nicht nur deshalb: +1, Dr. thei :)