# When to use "Der Reis" and when "Das Reis"?

Tags: noun

According to [translation site](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Reis) there is a two way for noun `Reis`, that is `der Reis` and `das Reis`.

Der Reis is a form that is commonly used, but what is with other one? In what situation is it used?

Comment: You also might find these related posts useful: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15698/words-with-multiple-genders-listed-in-dictionary http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1044/wie-kann-man-wissen-ob-zwei-w%c3%b6rter-homonyme-sind http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/can-teekesselchen-mean-homonym

Comment: As a native speaker, I never heard of 'das Reis' before ('Reisig' is familiar before). If somebody would have asked me the question in person, I probably would have said that 'das Reis' is a plain mistake.

Comment: *lach*, it's nice to see that almost no german speaker here knows that word :D

Answer (score 5):

*Das* Reis (pl. die Reiser) means "junger Trieb, dünner Zweig" (twig, sprig, brushwood) whereas *der* Reis (no plural) simply means rice. It's not very common outside of horticultural circles, I presume.

Comment: Well, "Reisig" is a word that used to be known outside horticultural circles - it may not be to younger generations, though.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I know "Reisig" and "Reiser" but not "Das Reis". I have always thought both "Reisig" and "Reiser" were dialect words (I am from Austria).

Comment: Funny how few german speakers know the word. Me neither (only Reisig).

Comment: Well, I'm not much into gardening, but I know that Reisig is a bunch of Reis(er) :-D A quick survey in my office showed that 100% of my collegues know the word "Das Reis".

Answer (score 5):

[Das Reis](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Reis_Spross_Zweig) means small branch or sprout

[Der Reis](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Reis_Pflanze_Korn) just means rice.

Comment: Though _Das Reis_ is extremely uncommon. So uncommon that I didn't even know it (I only knew `Reisig`).

Comment: @phresnel - I also had to look it up.

Comment: Thought it might be wort mentioning, just so that the asker does not get used to it, and then will permanently be corrected "No, lad, it's 'Der Reis, Der'" when he means a branch.

Comment: @phresnel And how stupid they would feel if a non-native-speaker was then able to say "No, lad, I'm talking about *das Reis* - little Branches, parts of plants".

Answer (score 3):

Ich halte "das Reis" (neuerTrieb, neuer Sproß/Zweig) für poetisch und veraltet. Ich kenne dieses Wort "ein Reis" nur aus einem alten Kirchenlied, sonst habe ich das Wort noch nie gesehen.

http://www.bouwebrouwer.nl/deutsche_gedichte/es_ist_ein_reis_entsprungen.html

Meistens hat die erste Zeile des Liedes die Form "Es ist ein Ros (poetisch für eine Rose) entsprungen. Vielleicht schon ein erster Hinweis, dass "Reis" nicht mehr so geläufig ist.

DWDS hat das Wort erfasst; dort wird allerdings keinerlei Hinweis gegeben, dass das Wort veraltet ist und nicht der modernen Sprache angehört.

http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=reis

Wenn man bei pons.eu (deutsch-englisch) Reis eingibt, findet man natürlich als Nr. 1 der Reis (Pflanze) und dann als Nr. 2 das Reis (sprig, twig), allerdings hat Pons.eu 
schon den Hinweis: veraltend.

Comment: Aber in der verwandten Form "Reisig" ist es durchaus (gerade zum nahenden Advent / Winter) für Bastler und Gärtner in aller Munde...

Comment: Mein Vater verwendet *das Reis* durchaus noch im Garten-Kontext. Die Verbreitung dieses Wortes mag ja abnehmend sein, aber noch ist es lebendig.

Comment: Ganz modern: "Es ist ein Ross entsprungen".

Comment: @userunknown: der Gaul ist abgehauen ;)

Comment: @userunknown: Als Kind hab ich tatsächlich immer "Ross" verstanden. Ergibt ja auch Sinn, wenn da ein Pferd rumspringt. - "ein Ros" für "eine Rose" empfand ich immer als ganz komisch, auch nachdem sich mein Missverständnis aufgeklärt hatte. :-) Dass das früher mal "Reis" hieß, erklärt für mich auch endlich, wo das "ein" herkommt.

Comment: Mir ging es als Kind genauso, für mich war das ein Ross und kein Mensch hat je versucht zu erklären, dass ein Ros eine Rose ist, aber eigentlich ein Reis war, und ein Reis hätten wir auch nicht verstanden.