# Zählen gleich geschriebene Wörter als dasselbe Wort, wenn sie unterschiedliche Bedeutung tragen?

Tags: grammar-identification

Anlass zu dieser Frage ist der Versuch hier, eine Liste deutscher Substantive mit mehreren Genera zu erstellen:

[Liste deutscher Substantive mit mehreren Genera](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/liste-deutscher-substantive-mit-mehreren-genera)

Dort werden mehrere Wörter aufgeführt, wie

> - **das/der Service**
>     Dienstleistung (Aussprache: [ˈsœːɐ̯vɪs])
>     das Service: In Österreich
>     der Service: Im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum (auch Ö)
>     Das mehrteilige Essgeschirr (Aussprache [zɛʁˈviːs]) ist überall sächlich

*Das* Service ist demnach immer das Essgeschirr, *der* Service (mit anderer Aussprache) immer die Dienstleistung.
Kann man hier sagen, dass es sich um **ein** Substantiv mit mehreren Genera handelt oder liegen hier zwei Substantive vor, die bloß gleich geschrieben werden?

Das ist eine grundlegende Frage:
Geht man davon aus, dass in dem Fall zwei unterschiedliche Wörter vorliegen, wäre es auch nicht unbedingt eine Frage von Sprachvarietäten (und auch sonst nicht überraschend), dass unterschiedliche Genera vorliegen (und dann bräuchte man diese auch nicht in besagter Liste führen).

Wenn man aber davon ausgeht, dass es sich um das selbe Wort handelt, *weil* die Schreibung gleich ist, müsste das dann nicht auf alle gleichgeschriebenen Wörter zutreffen?

> ich esse / die Esse
>   ich trank / der Trank
>   das Trinken (Vorgang) / das Trinken (das Getränk) (gleiches Genus = gleiches Wort?)

(Die Großschreibung von Nomen ist eine Konvention, die infrage gestellt wurde (z. B. von Jan Tschichold) und die in den meisten Sprachen nicht existiert.)

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29190/welche-vollst%c3%a4ndigen-teekesselchen-gibt-es und https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1044/wie-kann-man-wissen-ob-zwei-w%c3%b6rter-homonyme-sind

Comment: Es kommt nur darauf an wie man "dasselbe Wort" **definiert**. Meint man damit Homographen oder nicht?

Comment: @Philipp  Versuch, für dich selber zu klären, was Homonyme und was Polyseme sind, dann hast du die Antwort ... äh ... ohne Mühe selber gefunden. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Die Schlussfolgerung »Das Service ist demnach immer das Essgeschirr« ist falsch. Es steht ja ausdrücklich da:

> Dienstleistung (Aussprache: [ˈsœːɐ̯vɪs])
> das Service: In Österreich
> der Service: Im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum (auch Ö)

Das bedeutet, dass die Dienstleistung in Österreich sächlich und männlich, und überall außerhalb Österreichs nur männlich ist. Der Satz

> **Das** Service dieser Werkstätte ist schlecht.

ist im österreichischen Deutsch vollkommen korrekt. Er könnte so in einer österreichischen Tageszeitung stehen und würde in einem Schulaufsatz nicht als fehlerhaft bemängelt. In Deutschland wäre das - wie mir gesagt wurde - nicht so.

Der Satz

> **Der** Service dieser Werkstätte ist schlecht.

wird im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum als korrekt empfunden, auch in Österreich. Damit hat das Wort *»Service«*, wenn damit eine Dienstleitung gemeint ist, in Österreich zwei Genera und gehört somit in die Liste.

Um jedoch klar zu machen, dass dies für ein Homonym (nämlich das Tafelgeschirr) nicht gilt, wurde noch folgender Satz hinzugefügt:

> Das mehrteilige Essgeschirr (Aussprache [zɛʁˈviːs]) ist überall sächlich.

Damit ist gemeint, dass der Satz

> <del>**Der** Service, der bei Tante Emma auf dem Tisch steht, ist aus Porzellan.</del>

überall falsch ist. In der Schweiz, in Österreich, in Deutschland, wo sonst noch Deutsch gesprochen wird. Richtig ist überall nur dieser Satz:

> **Das** Service, das bei Tante Emma auf dem Tisch steht, ist aus Porzellan.

---

Ein anderer Fall liegt beim Wort **Abwasch** vor. Hier sind:

- > **der** Abwasch
  > Vorgang des Abwaschens
- > **die** Abwasch
  > Spülbecken

tatsächlich zwei Homonyme, von denen jedes für sich in nur einem Geschlecht vorkommt. Von diesen beiden wird eines im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum verwendet (*der Abwasch*), das andere (*die Abwasch*) gehört nur einer der drei Standardvarietäten an, nämlich dem österreichischen Deutsch. Die Verbreitung hat aber keinen Einfluss darauf ob es in die Liste gehört oder nicht.

In diesem Fall trifft also das Argument des Fragestellers, dass es zwei semantisch verschiedene Begriffe sind, tatsächlich zu. Ähnlich ist es bei

- *die Band* (Musikgruppe)
- *der Band* (Buch)
- *das Band* (Stoffstreifen)

In diesem Fall kann man nur sagen: Das ist eine Sache der Definition. Es gibt für beide Standpunkte (ein Wort mit mehreren Bedeutungen - mehrere verschiedene Wörter die zufällig gleich geschrieben und manchmal sogar gleich ausgesprochen werden) gute Argumente.